# Display image size in MB format IOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, image-size

I tying to check my image size after picking form the photo library by using this code.

```
 NSData *imageData1 = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation((imageview.image), 0.5)];

   int imageSize = imageData1.length;
   NSLog(@"SIZE OF IMAGE: %i ", imageSize);
```

But showing something like this .

```
SIZE OF IMAGE: 237125
```

But i want to view the image size in the MB format like 25 MB how to do pls tell me how to do it.

thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`imageSize` has data length in bytes. You need to convert it to Mb

```
NSLog(@"SIZE OF IMAGE: %i Mb", imageSize/1024/1024);
```

UPDATE:

You can also use following code

```
NSLog(@"SIZE OF IMAGE: %.2f Mb", (float)imageSize/1024/1024);
```

to receive output like

> SIZE OF IMAGE: 0.23 Mb

for sizes less the 1 Mb.

Comment: now its showing 0mb in console pls tell me how to relsolve this

Comment: It is because 237125 bytes is less then 1 Mb.

Comment: i have checked with some high size image but its still showing 0 mb only

Comment: Probably it was also less then 1 Mb. Please try second variant from my answer.

Answer (score 15):

```
[NSByteCountFormatter stringFromByteCount:imageSize 
                      countStyle:NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleFile];
```

Comment: Yup, this should be marked as the correct answer, I added my own with a version in Swift

Answer (score 1):

Complementing @rounak 's answer, in **Swift 3**:

```
ByteCountFormatter.string(fromByteCount: Int64(imageSize), countStyle: .file)
```